# How to check if week number is even or odd in ANSI C?

Tags: c, date

I`ve a small app that returns is week even or not.

```
time_t now = time(0); 
tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
int twin=(ltm->tm_yday/7)%2
```

But independently from the 1st day of the year so it returns

mon, thu, we, etc
0,1,1,1,1,1,1
in the next week
1,0,0,0,0,0,0

In the next year
mon, thu, we, etc
0,0,1,1,1,1,1
in the next week
1,1,0,0,0,0,0

 and so on..
Twin- if number modulo 2 = 0
So I have to add shift to change week number in each sunday or monday. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish. It isn't at all clear.

Comment: What you call "twin" is usually called "odd". Day of the week (i.e. mon, tue, wed, etc.) does not play into the answer a slightest bit: you should be checking Jan-1, Jan-2, Jan-3, ... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that first week has exactly 7 days which is incorrect.

For example Jan 1st 2013 was Tuesday, so the first week is only 5 days long.

How about using strftime? Something like:

```
time_t now = time(0); 
tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
char weekNr[3];
strftime(weekNr, sizeof(weekNr), "%W", ltm);
int isOdd = atoi(weeknr) % 2;
```

Comment: Thx, the simplest way is the best

Answer (score 0):

What you call *twin*, in English is usually called *even*.

About your question, the issue here is that you are not calculating the week number correctly: you are simply dividing by 7, and that's not enough because the start of year and the start of week vary each year.

Moreover, there are several different ways to decide which one is week 1. See for example [this code](http://www.adsb.co.uk/date_and_time/week_numbers/isowknum.c), to get started.

**UPDATE**: Copying shamelessly from the eglibc source code:

1) The week number of the current year as a decimal number, range 00 to 53,  starting  with  the  first Sunday as the first day of week 01 (`strftime("%U")`):

```
tp->tm_yday - tp->tm_wday + 7) / 7
```

2) The week number of the current year as a decimal number, range 00 to 53,  starting  with  the  first Monday as the first day of week 01 (`strftime("%W")`):

```
(tp->tm_yday - (tp->tm_wday - 1 + 7) % 7 + 7) / 7
```

3) The  ISO 8601 week number (see NOTES) of the current year as a decimal number, range 01 to 53, where week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the new year  (`strftime("%V")`):

Well this is complicated... so you are better with the idea by @MaikuMori of using ``` strftime``, but with ```"%V"`, and then parse the result, with`atoi()`.

Comment: Thanks for example, now I can see it.